# mouse events on div position absolute dont fire in Chrome or Firefox but do in IE

Tags: html, css-position

I'm using position:absolute to build some custom buttons which work fine in IE(9) but not in Chrome(19) or Firefox (12) with this simple bit of code:

```
<div  id="FileDetailsDisptBoxToolTip" title="^ToolTip" 
style="position: fixed; left: 15px; top: 310px;  width:60px; height: 20px;">
    <img src="newButtonImages/infoTrack.png"  width=60 height=20
         onmouseover="dispFileDetails()" onmouseout="hideFileDetails()"/>
</div>
```

In IE the mouse events fire and the title displays as a tool tip. In Chrome and FF, there's no mouse events and no tool tip.
I've tried lots of permutations - only when I remove position: fixed; does it work, but then I lose the essential positioning. 
I'd be happy with a work-around.

Comment: Without a link, or some javascript code, it's all just a wild guess. In any case, while it may be working in IE, it's not working in a modern browser, so your code is wrong. Never, ever use IE as a reference for how things should work.

Comment: I have put up a demo of this at http://www.gpsanimator.com/demo . In IE the onmouseover/onmouseout and title as tool tip work on the top image. In Chrome, FF and Sadfari on Mac, they don't work, even though the tool tip on the lower image works in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Cracked it!
Seems Chrome, FF and Safari are fussy about the order in which the elements are located in the html.
If they are out of sequence, as in my demo:

`<div   title="ToolTip" style="position: fixed; left: 15px; top: 310px;  width:60px; height: 20px;">
        <img src="newButtonImages/infoTrack.png"  width=60 height=20
            onmouseover="dispFileDetails()" onmouseout="hideFileDetails()">

     </div>
    <div   style="position: absolute; top:158px; left:10px; width: 160px; height: 180px;">

        <span id="infoDisplay" ></span>
    </div> 
    <div style="position: fixed; top:375px; left:8px; width: 165px; height: 240px;
    background-image: url(newButtonImages/mapImage.png); background-repeat: no-repeat" title="map_canvas tip"/>
    .....
    </div>`

where I declare the first div with top: 310px, then one at top:158px and finally one at 165px, it fails in all but IE. If I declare them in the order 158px, 165px and then 310px the problem goes away.
See http://www.gpsanimator.com/demo/x.html - it works across the range of browsers!
Now how's that for an annoying little feature?

Comment: So all the more modern browsers act the same way and IE is different yet you think the modern browsers are fussy? I just woke up and haven't looked at your "fix" but I can assure you that, until you learn to quit looking to IE as a reference for how things should work, you will continue to struggle with web development.

Comment: Rob, Your unhelpful, anti-IE paranoia has reached a nadir. When you do take the time to read the solution, you'll find that I'm not looking to IE as a reference at all. I'm not an apologist for IE, just trying to work out how to get a the "modern browsers" to perform to spec! 
Your suggestion about <!DOCTYPE html> was a waste of time. I always find it's a good plan to test a theory before proposing it as a solution.

The reason I'm returning to IE is that it delivers a far superior animation performance. The others are so so desperately cycle-hungry that my app struggles to get off the ground

Comment: Since you are unwilling to add the doctype, you can't be helped. It's an amateur's mistake. It shows you don't know how coding for browsers works. Doctypes are required for today's web and if you consider that an anti-IE stance, then you have far too much to learn for anyone to help you here.

Comment: Of course I tried your suggestion about the doctype - it made no difference. I would hardly have made the comment about it being a waste of time without  actually having wasted the time.

Comment: I missed that, but it doesn't matter. You can NOT create web pages today without one. What you have working today will not work as you move on. Here's the current spec for you: http://developers.whatwg.org/syntax.html#the-doctype

Comment: I have read your reference and am even more convinced that it's a red herring. The opening phrase: "..required for legacy reasons.." convinces me that it has no effect whatsoever on modern browsers.

Comment: Did you stop reading there? A doctype is needed because of PROBLEMS with legacy browsers. This is not the place to carry on a discussion but this is also an extremely fundamental requirement. I suggest you read this and Google for more before you attempt anything else. Especially the part about choosing a doctype. http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

Comment: Of course I read the whole section, my attention span is quite adequate for that. The problem I'm describing was never with with a "Legacy browser" (whatever that really means??) It's a problem with Chrome Version 16 and Firefox Version 12 I don't think they qualify as Legacy browsers - do you? Perhaps you could turn your attention to the problem I'm reporting and let this go?

Comment: I already did. You keep looking at IE and saying "it works" without realizing your markup is wrong and FF/Chrome are showing what you wrote. Until you want to learn the basics of html, you can't be helped any further. And that's all I have to say about this.

Answer (score 0):

Per my previous comments, the problem lies with IE. Without a proper doctype, you are in quirks mode, and you will never get IE to attempt to perform like the other far more modern browsers. Add this to your first line and then see where we stand `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Until you add that, there is no way to tell what other issues IE is having with this.